# Wildcard SSL - Do I need another SSL for subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I'm not sure if I could word it right. I know that Wildcards SSLs will support any amount of subdomains in a domain. But does it also support subdomains of already existent subdomains?

I'm about to buy a wildcard SSL but I need to have this kind of setup: subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com

Will I need more certificates or will only one wildcard certificate be enough?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes wildcards can support sub domains of already existent sub domains, but there are different criteria to secure your domain and sub domains and multi level sub domains.

**First:** If you only need to secure your *.subdomain.domain.com

In this case you can secure your all sub domains with single Wildcard SSL. CSR require to be generated on subdomain.domain.com – Wildcard SSL will only work with this condition.

The caveat to choosing wildcard ssl to secure your multi level sub domain is it will not cover your top level domain. If someone tries to access your https://domain.com then they will find domain name mismatch error in web browser.

**Second:** If you want to secure your entire website.

Including all of the following:

```
domain.com         (top level domain)
*.domain.com       (sub domain)
*.*.domain.com     (sub sub domain)
```

You need to secure your whole website with single UCC/SAN Certificate. It will help you to secure all above conditional webpages with the use of Subject Alternative Name (SAN) certificate.

Hope now you understand what to do. Know your business needs perfectly and choose the certificate.